# OptionT in Java? Is it possible?

Tags: java, scala, monads

I'm impressed about monad transformers provided by ScalaZ and now interested if it's possible to implement something like `OptionT` in Java?

In Scala we can use `TypeClass`es for this which simplifies implementation. Is there something like this in Java?

Comment: You might be interested in Cyclops: https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/introducing-the-cyclops-monad-api-a7a6b7967f4d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `OptionT` is a *higher-kinded type constructor*, meaning it takes a *type constructor* (as opposed to a type) as an argument. Java doesn't support higher-kinded type constructors, in Java, a type constructor (aka *generic class / interface*) can only take types as arguments and return types.

Type constructors are quite similar to functions, except on the type level. A function (which in some branches of mathematics is also called a *value constructor*) takes values as arguments and returns values. If it takes a function as an argument and/or returns a function, then it is called a *higher-order* function. Not everything allows higher-order functions, e.g. C doesn't support them.

Similarly, a type constructor takes types as arguments and returns types (it "constructs types from types", e.g. the `List` type constructor will construct a type "list of integers", when you pass it `Int` as an argument). Similarly to functions, when a type constructor can take a type constructor as argument or returns a type constructor, then it is called *higher-kinded*, and they are not supported everywhere. In particular, Java doesn't allow them.

**NOTE**: You *can* actually say something like `Foo<Foo>` in Java, but that is *not* a higher-kinded type constructor. The two `Foo`s here are actually different things: the first `Foo` is the *generic type* `Foo<T>`, the *second* `Foo` is the *raw type* `Foo`, which is an artifact of the way generics were introduced in Java 5.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, but with a lot of trickery: https://github.com/highj/highj/blob/master/src/main/java/org/highj/data/transformer/MaybeT.java

The mentioned https://github.com/highj/highj library simulates higher order polymorphism with normal generics. As a consequence, you have to manually convert results in higher-order representation back to their "normal" form.